# Ironpython: How to see when a WPF application fails?

Tags: wpf, xaml, ironpython, sharpdevelop

I am doing an application with GUI using `WPF`/`XAML` with `Ironpython` and `SharpDevelop`, until now it works fine, when I'm in the development environment I can see the errors in console and know what is wrong.

But when I build and deploy the app for us on other system  or I ran it outside of the development environment and there is no longer the console when there is some error or  crashes, it fails silently, and I cannot know what went wrong.

How can I alert or log to see what fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put in some code to catch the error and log it to a file.

Something possibly simpler is to compile your application as a Console Application. This can be done via Project Options - Application - Output type. Then you will get a console window when you run your WPF application and any exception that happens at startup will be logged to this window.